# Set different _id and id fields with Spring Data Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I understand that Spring Data maps by default id field to the elastic _id. Is this some way to override this behavior?
I have a document with id field that came from outside and I don't want to change its name because of backward compatibility. But I have to support the scenario when I have multiple docs with the same id (it's not unique field) 
So I want to let elastic to generate _id field to be unique and set my own id
Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 4):

Spring Data Elasticsearch identifies the id property by either the `@Id` annotation or by the property name if it is *id* or *document*. So you get  a conflict when having both the annotation and a field with one of these names.

In Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.0, you can change the name of the *id* property:

```
@Document(indexName = "sample-entities")
public class SampleEntity {

    @Id
    private String autogeneratedId;  // (1)

    @Field(name = "no-id")           // (2)
    private String id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String message;

    // getter/setter omitted for brevity
}
```

(1) this field will be used for the _id in Elasticsearch and will get an autogenerated value from Elasticsearch.

(2) this field will be named *no-id* in Elasticsearch and will not be identified as id field because of the renaming in the `@Field` annotation.

If you are using Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.2, you need to [`ElasticsearchEntityMapper`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/3.2.7.RELEASE/reference/html/#elasticsearch.mapping.meta-model) instead of the default Jackson based one.